# foreign key issue with my department model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting  the following error Cannot assign "u'167'": "Department.organization" must be a "Organization" instance.

I have tried every way to send the Organization id but with no success:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8081/profiles/api/createorganisation/
Django Version: 1.8.14
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "u'167'": "Department.organization" must be a "Organization" instance.

Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 639
```

This is the model

```
class Department(models.Model):
"""
Make department codes selectable and stuff
"""
organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="departments")
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, editable=False)
users = models.ManyToManyField("CustomUser", related_name="departments", blank=True)
enter code here
```

Serializer class

```
class DepartmentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
organization = serializers.CharField()
name = serializers.CharField()
slug = serializers.CharField()


class Meta:
    model = Department
    fields = ('pk','organization','name','slug')
```

This is my code

```
  org = Organization.objects.get(slug="tata5").id

    department = { 
        "organization":org,
        "name" : "finance1",
        "slug" : "finance1" ,
     }  
    
  
    logging.warning(department)
    
   
    instance = DepartmentCreateSerializer(data=department)
    instance.organization = org
    instance.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    instance.save()
    

    # createDepartment.is_valid()
    # createDepartment.save()
    
    return Response(instance, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `serializers.CharField()` so it's trying to set `department.organization = 'id'` instead of it being an actual `Organization` instance, what you should be using instead is a [`serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) that will then serialize the ID input into an `Organization` instance.